# Call to undefined method Exception::getSeverity()

Tags: php

I am using [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) as my central error handling function for Errors and Exception:

Example:

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');    

function my_error_handler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    my_exception_handler(new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline));
}

function my_exception_handler ($e)
{   
    echo $e->getSeverity();
    echo $e->getCode();
    echo $e->getMessage();          
}
```

Now it appears `$e->getSeverity();` is only present in `ErrorException` and not in the default `Exception`;

Because when I `throw new Exception('test');` I get a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Exception::getSeverity()`.

But when I `throw new ErrorException('test');` it works as expected.

This seems logical but is there a way I can still use `throw new Exception('test');` without getting the Fatal Error? Most third-party libraries use Exception (not ErrorException) so it will be problematic when a third-party exception occurs, it will cause Fatal Error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the caught exception is an `ErrorException`:

```
if ($e instanceof ErrorException) {
    echo $e->getSeverity();
} else {
    // no getSeverity() available
}
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds :)  Nice answer, was thinking the same thing.